# Create all sets size 2 of several columns

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm using Maria DB 10.1.16 and I am looking for the most often occuring set size 2 of several columns.

Example Database:

```
ID |  Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Result ID | EXPECTED RESULT
1       1       0       2        1         "Col 1/ Col 3"        
2       1       0       0    No Results
3       1       1       3        3         "Col 1/ Col 2"
                                 3         "Col 1/ Col 3"
                                 3         "Col 2/ Col 3"
```

With this new column I'd just Count and GroupBy to receive how often which set would occur.

I am not quite sure about an elegant way to transfer this however. The baseline solution would be to check every row of the existence of all possible sets:

```
SELECT *,"Col 1/ Col 2" AS FreqSet 
FROM `Table` 
WHERE Col 1 >0 AND Col 2 >0

UNION SELECT *,"Col 1/ Col 3" AS FreqSet 
FROM `Table` 
WHERE Col 1 >0 AND Col 3 >0

UNION SELECT *,"Col 2/ Col 3" AS FreqSet 
FROM `Table` 
WHERE Col 2 >0 AND Col 3 >0
Order By ID
```

However as I want to do this for a total of 8 columns the result would be 28 SELECT statements to cover all combinations. So I am hoping for a better solution ^^.

Side note I also have another view containing all entries >0 in one column like this:

```
ID ColTotal
1     Col1
1     Col3
2     Col1
3     Col1
3     Col2
3     Col3
```

Maybe someone has a better queue for that view. I hope I have covered everything?

Thanks for any tips in advance!
Greetings Hasorko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view is much more useful.  This is just a `join`:

```
select distinct v1.id, concat(v1.col, '/', v2.col) 
from v v1 join
     v v2
     on v1.id = v2.id and v1.col < v2.col;
```

Comment: Solution works, but created duplicates for me. I.e.:

Comment: (Accidently send comment above) :S no edit?
Anyway created duplicates solved it with Distinct at Select. Thanks a bunch